# how to create a class instance in iphone?

Tags: iphone, object, sdk, instance

noob question (new to objective c) i have created an utility application in xcode and i would like to create an instance of class "Fish" in my mainviewcontroller (so i can use the functions from Fish in mainviewcontroller). How is this possible? I tried this in the header file - mainviewcontroller under implementation "Fish *fish = [[Fish alloc] init]; " however i get an error ("expected specifier-qualifier-list before). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this at the top of the file:

```
#import "Fish.h"
```

Somewhere in your code.

```
Fish *fish = [[Fish alloc] init];
```

Don't forget to clean up!

```
[fish release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare class Fish and make it visible to your mainviewcontroller by importing the appropriate header file.

Here is tutorial for the very beginner: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler doesn't know the class Fish. You have to tell him about the class.

add `#import "Fish.h"` at the beginning of the MainViewController.m file, and if you made Fish an instance variable you should put `@class Fish;` above `@interface MainViewController` in your MainViewController.h file.